# Electron JS/Node JS desktop app as a local network webserver

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application

Is it possible to make an Electron JS desktop app that is a web server, so that when we start the app the server will also start and we can access it from other computer within the same network/LAN?

Comment: Why not? HTTP is a native module in NodeJS so you can import in electron with no problem. Have you tried something?

Comment: I have made a server with node js and will implement a express js web app.
I am thinking to make Electron app for installing the server(with node js and my express app/dependency install) in the system and when user will start the electron app the server will start and other system can access it with browser.

But I am not sure about It will allow users to access there Printer/Scanner/Barcode Scanner through web browser. 

Any idea?

Comment: Any luck with this @Shashank, I am trying to do something similar too. Not sure if something like "make an electron app accessible over LAN" is possible.

Comment: @BkBaba, yes I have developed it successfully, I have made an Electron desktop app which starting a server in system (LAN) and inside it I am using Express for API. And I have made a client side desktop app in electron which is calling server API's.

Also for making system IP(server) static I have made entry in router with system(server) mac address to allot it static IP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

Yout can run you server (express or just bare `http`/`https`/`http2`) on main process.

Also you can `child_process.fork()` or `child_process.spawn()`. It works fine.